# What is the verification speed for syncing a Waves node?

Tags: nodes, blockchain, wavesplatform

I'm syncing my Waves node for 3 days now. Its very slow. 100 blocks update every 3 min or so. Im on a 4gb ubuntu server. what is the verification speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verification speed depends on your CPU resources. RAM is also valuable, but CPU needs to be fast for good speed. We added some explanations [here](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-full-node/options-for-getting-actual-blockchain.html#section-49f3f73cf07e96b18cb17deb1edc14c2). Also the bottleneck could be in your hard drive (we recommend using SSD), or network.

Verification is not a linear operation, “heavy” blocks are verified longer. The ”heaviness" of a block is determined by the number and type of transactions it contains. So the first blocks (for example, the first 200.000) are empty and verified much faster than the same number of blocks after the million